# Android Studio - How to Update UI elements of Fragments?

Tags: java, android

I'm in the process of programming an app where it is necessary to display different data in different fragments of an activity and update it in real time. So data is read from an SQLLite database and displayed in TextViews. However, these data are constantly changing and therefore the TextViews have to change their content constantly.

I tried to do it this way (This is placed in every Fragment of the mainActivity with different processes inside `run()`):

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(!isInterrupted()){

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DBOpenHelper db = new DBOpenHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                            SQLiteDatabase read = db.getReadableDatabase();
                            Cursor c = read.query("save", new String[] {"id", "balance"}, null, null, null, null, null);

                            String sCursor = "a";
                            if (c != null) {
                                c.moveToFirst();
                                sCursor = c.getString(1);
                            }
                            tvBalance.setText("$" + sCursor);
                            c.close();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

The problem is that the memory of the Android Device Emulator gets permanently full and after a while the app crashes.

So how is it possible to update the UI elements of the different fragments more efficiently?

Edit: These fragments are fragments of a tab_fragment of a Navigation Drawer Activity. The TextViews of those fragments are inside a ScrollView. So if I would just detach and reattach the fragment the ScrollView wouldn't be at the position it was before the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is not good practice to copy paste your code in different classes (use one base class instead and extend it in your child fragments). Secondly, it is good practice to place your application logic and thread operations in activity and call from fragment to respective function through some interface. You can look up more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). Also there is no need for opening new thread each time you make request to database (for initial steps you can use `AsyncTask`). So please review your application logic in the root. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could benefit from `Reactive` components, that you store your value in them and any interested part of your program of that value can `subscribe` to the component to get notified whenever the value changes.
some of those components are the `LiveData` and `BehaviorSubject`.
in your case that you are dealing with `SQLite`, [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) are your ultimate solution, `Room` can generate a `LiveData` object that get triggered every time your data changes.